# Change default name for matplotlib Qt GUI savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I can change the default directory, as the save file dialog seems to draw from `matplotlib.rcParams["savefig.directory"]`, but I can't find any option for changing the default name from `"image"` to e.g. my own `self.currentFigure` variable.

To save the figure I'm using the NavigationToolbar2QT from the Matplotlib Qt5 backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the default filename `"image"` is hardcoded in the `FigureCanvas`.
Supposedly you are creating your program by using `FigureCanvasQTAgg`? In that case you can subclass it to return a different default string.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

# ..

class MyFigureCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def get_window_title(self):
        return "my_default_filename"
```

and then at the point where you'd normally `self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(...)`, you'd use your custom canvas, e.g. as

```
self.canvas = MyFigureCanvas(...)
```

resulting in

[image]